# PATCH method set NULL to values instead of the value

Tags: json, vuejs2, axios, symfony4, api-platform.com

How is it possible to insert multiple row in json via Postman ?

I tried this :

```json
[{
    "name": "Choix 1",
    "question": "Question 1"
},
{
    "name": "Choix 3",
    "question": "Question 44"
}
]
```

EDIT.
I saw in the documentation that it is not possible like that.

I added a denormalization group in my API and now I can add several data at the same time thanks to the PATCH method. But now, the problem is that when I add a second time, it removes a part of the previous data.

Example : in "question_study" I have my "question_id" 156, 157, 160 which don't have any "study_ID" whereas they had some before I send him a new question (161) which has its id number .... And if I send him several at once they all have a study_id but if I re-try, the "study_id" disappear....

[image]

```
axios
        .patch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/studies/' + this.idStudy, 
             data, 
             { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/merge-patch+json' }})
        .then((result)=>{
          console.log(result)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("ERRRR:: ",error.result.data);
        });
```

In my console console.log(result) : the header content-type is "application/ld+json; charset=utf-8" while I put 'application/merge-patch+json' in my request.

And this is a piece of my db :
[image]

Comment: Please provide the `@ApiResource` configuration for the resource that you're interacting with.

Comment: There is an [issue about batch operations](https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/1645)

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a beginner so I don't understand how it can helps me to fix my problem...

Answer (score 0):

> How is it possible to insert multiple row in json via Postman [into ApiPlatform]?

It isn't.

At least, not using default generated routes from ApiPlatform for its resources. Docs here: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/

Any generated POST route will only accept a single resource.

If you want to be able to do batch inserts, you will have to create a custom endpoint and probably a collection denormalizer.

Comment: Yah I tried with denormalization group but I have still a problem. I edit my first message to understand

Comment: I edit my first message because the problem is very weird

Comment: Do you have  an idea ?